# JQuery - darker div when hover on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want something like [this link](http://wella.com/professional/en-US/salon-finder). If user hover header section another part of page will be darker than normal. Here is my code:

**Index.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
    $(function(){       
      $("#generalHeader").load("header.html"); 
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">    
    <div id="generalHeader"></div>      
    <div class="yellow">
    </div>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now , my page look likes this :
[image]

I want to *yellow* section will be darker if user hover on *generalHeader*.

Any suggestion?

Comment: _"I want something like"_ What have you tried ?

Comment: set the body background color to black, and change the opacity of your yellow div on the hover and mouseout events.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `css` `:hover` , `filter` , `brightness` , `transition`

```css
section {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:yellow;
  transition: all 1s;
}

header {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width:298px;
  text-align:center;
}

header:hover + section {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(0.8);
  -moz-filter: brightness(0.8);
  filter: brightness(0.8);
}
```

```html
<header>hover</header>
<section></section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the background color of the body to black (or overlay the yellow div on top of a black div), and then change the opacity of the yellow div in the relevant event handlers.

```
$(function() {
  $("#generalHeader").hover(function() {
    $(".yellow").stop().fadeTo(1200, .5);
  });

  $("#generalHeader").mouseout(function() {
    $(".yellow").stop().fadeTo(600, 1);
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tonyhinkle/Lmuun72f/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just changing the color, but you can try playing with the opacity too. Take a look using JQuery:

```
function headerHover(){
 $("#generalHeader").hover(
    function(){
        // Opacity
        $(".yellow").css("opacity", "0.6");
        // Color
        $(".yellow").css("background-color", "#A8A810");
    }, 
    function(){
        // Return to normal when mouse leave
        $(".yellow").css("opacity", "1");

        $(".yellow").css("background-color", "yellow");
    })
};
```

As you can see hover() takes two functions, the first one is what to do on mouse hover and the second if when mouse leave. I used the classes in the code you posted just change "generalHeader" and "yellow" for what you need.

Now also you can do it adding a CSS class:

CSS file:

```
.mainHover{
    opacity:0.6;
    bakground-color:#A8A810;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function headerHover(){
     $("#generalHeader").hover(
        function(){           
            $(".yellow").addClass("mainHover");

        }, 
        function(){
            // Return to normal when mouse leave
            $(".yellow").removeClass("mainHover");          
         })
    };
```